# Possible to have # start a comment that ends at EOL or at next #, whichever comes first?

Tags: listings, languages, sourcecode

I'm trying to create a `listings` language in which the `#` symbol starts a comment that ends at the end of the line or at the next `#` symbol encountered, whichever comes first.

Of course, I'd like to capture the `#` symbols themselves as well.

Is there any way to achieve the desired effect?

## What I want

[image]

## What I have

The code corresponding to this unsuccessful attempt can be found below at it, along with some example comments I'd like to highlight (the space-padding inconsistencies are intentional).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\lstdefinelanguage{Test}
{
  morecomment=[s][\color{blue}]{\#}{\#},
  morecomment=[l][\color{red}]{\#}
}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Test]
  #comment
  foo # comment# bar #comment # dec
  baz # comment
  #comment# qux
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please review Andrew's edited answer. It seems to match your requirements, now. If it does, please accept it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit**

In view of the discussion below I am now assuming that you want the  comments of the form `#...#` to always be on the same line. As far as I can tell the `listings` package does not support comments with two delimiters that *must* be on on the same line. I had a look at the package internals and have hacked them so that the L-type is a combination of the l and s types. The following code works on your example and seems to work in general, although as this is a hack perhaps it misses some corner cases, or it breaks something else?

What I have done is define a new comment *type* `L` that has opening and closing delimiters and is confined to one line (at least this is what I think I have done:). With my hack I get the following output on (an extended version of) your example:

[image]

Here is the latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\gdef\lst@commenttypes{l,L,f,s,n}
\gdef\lst@CommentDM@L#1#2#3\@empty#4#5#6{%
    \lst@CArg #2\relax\lst@DefDelimB{}{}{}#4{#1}{#6\lst@Lmodetrue}%
    \lst@CArg #3\relax\lst@DefDelimE{}{}{}#5{#1}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\lstdefinelanguage{Test}
{
  morecomment=[L][\color{red}]{\#}{\#},
}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Test]
  #comment
  foo # comment# bar #comment # dec
  baz # comment
  #comment# qux
  code # a comment
  more code # more comments
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I should explain in more detail how the new `L` comment type works. The syntax is

> morecomment=[L]{⟨delimiter⟩}{⟨delimiter⟩}

The corresponding comments can either start with the first delimiter and go to the end of the line (where the comment finishes), or the comment stops at the second delimiter if it appears on the same line. This is why only one comment type needs to be declared in the OPs example above. By the same reasoning, the start and end delimiters do not have to be the same so if, instead, we wrote:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{Test}{
  morecomment=[L][\color{blue}]{(*}{*)},
}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Test]
  (*comment
  foo (* comment*) bar (*comment *) dec
  baz (* comment
  (*comment*) qux
  code (* a comment
  more code (* more comments
\end{lstlisting}
```

then the output becomes

[image]

I won't explain the commands that I lifted from the `listings` package as this would take a while. I do want to say, however, that the ease with which you can do this is a testament to the authors of the `listings` package.

Comment: The problem here is that `bar` and `qux` are coloured red, meaning the comment matching did not end at the second # symbol, which is exactly the problem I ran into.

Comment: @Thanix This is why including a MWE is a good idea. This isn't at all clear from your question. If no one else has figured it out I'll look at it again in the morning as it's late here.

Comment: I've edited the question and provided the MWE you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: This answer outlines the problems I ran into, but does not propose a solution.

Comment: @Thanix Actually, I would say that I have explained why what you want to do will not work. If you use the same symbol, in your case `#`, for marking both end-of-line comments and multiline comments then it is impossible to tell whether a given `#` starts a one line or multiline comment. You need to change your commenting system so that the two variants are logically distinguishable. [I also showed you how to define the comments, which you then used for your MWE.]

Comment: So you are saying that what I am to do is impossible?

Comment: @Thanix I don't know the listings package well enough to say that this is not possible. What I am saying is that if you define multiline comments to have the form `#....#` then this seems to be  incompatible with having single line comments of the form `#...`. How are you meant to tell these two apart? In all of the langauges that I known which support two comments conventions like this all use different symbols to diferentiate between single and multipline comments.

Comment: @Andrew Note that the OP is not asking for multiline comments. If you take that into account, there is no ambiguity in the following requirement: "*I want the # symbol to start a comment that ends at the end of the line or another # symbol, whichever comes first.*"

Comment: @Jubobs I think that it is ambiguous as to whether, in the second case, the second # has to be on the same line as the first one. Certainly the s-type commments in the listings package do not require this...but I agree that these comments are well-defined with this restriction. I have replaced my solution with one that defines a new comment style that captures this.

Comment: @Andrew Nice. Your solution works fine, as far as I can tell. I'll wait until the OP gets back to you, but it looks like you're going to get my bounty `:)`

Comment: @Jubobs Thank you, but the credits really should go to the package authors...it feels a little strange that I should get credit for being slow in finding a solution:) I've added a little more detail about what my hack does.

Comment: Your solution works (even for all the corner cases I managed to come up with), and despite being cryptic, is exactly what I had hoped for to begin with (i.e. an additional comment type). Nicely done.

Comment: @Andrew I'm going to wait for a while before I award the bounty to you; that way, you can reap all the rep' from increased exposure as possible.

Comment: @Thanix I'm glad it's helpful. Apologies for misunderstanding your question originally. I said above that your question was ambiguous but in fact what you wanted is completely clear from the title, so the mistake is all mine - sorry!

Comment: @Andrew For information, I edited the title. The original one wasn't as clear, IMO, so don't beat yourself up.

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks very much Jubobs! I'll repost some of this as another bounty at some point following the pay-it-forward model.